# CTC loss doesn't decrease using tensorflow, while it decreases using Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras

There is an OCR implementation using Keras, it works fine.

I'm now trying to re-implement it in tensorflow, see code [Here](https://github.com/altiplanogao/confusing-ctc). They share same model definition:

1. General CNN, (Input: 32*280*1, Output: 1*35*512)
2. TimeDistributed Full Connected: (Input: 35*512, Output: 35*3000)

While training, ctc_loss is used. And they both use adam optimizer to minimize the loss (although seems that tensorflow and keras have different adam implementation)

The result is that keras version's ctc_loss will decrease, and tf version will not.

1. Keras loss and optimizer definition (in keras_train.py):

   ```
   def ctc_lambda_func(args):
       base_output, labels, label_length = args
       base_output_shape = tf.shape(base_output)
       sequence_length = tf.fill([base_output_shape[0],], base_output_shape[1])
       return K.ctc_batch_cost(labels, base_output, sequence_length, label_length)
   loss = Lambda(ctc_lambda_func, output_shape=(1,), name='ctc')([base_output, labels, label_length])

   train_model = Model(inputs=[base_input, labels, label_length], outputs=loss)
   def loss_func(y_true, y_pred):
       return y_pred
   train_model.compile(loss={'ctc': loss_func}, optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
   ```
2. Tensorflow loss and optimizer definition (in tf_train.py):

   ```
   self.loss = tf.nn.ctc_loss(labels=self.labels,
                              inputs=self.logits,
                              sequence_length=self.seq_len,
                              time_major=False)
   self.cost = tf.reduce_mean(self.loss)
   self.optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=Config.LEARNING_RATE)
   self.train_op = self.optimizer.minimize(self.loss, global_step=self.global_step)
   ```

I also change adam to different optimizers, the result is that keras version always decrease, and tenserflow version never.

Can anyone help me out? Many many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue and observation that ctc_batch_cost was clue.
K.ctc_batch_cost is just wrapper to use tf.ctc_loss and convert softmax y_pred like below
in code
after adding this coversion, the issue has been fixed.

**y_pred = math_ops.log(array_ops.transpose(y_pred, perm=[1, 0, 2]) + epsilon())**

```
    def ctc_batch_cost(y_true, y_pred, input_length, label_length):
  """Runs CTC loss algorithm on each batch element.
  Arguments:
      y_true: tensor `(samples, max_string_length)`
          containing the truth labels.
      y_pred: tensor `(samples, time_steps, num_categories)`
          containing the prediction, or output of the softmax.
      input_length: tensor `(samples, 1)` containing the sequence length for
          each batch item in `y_pred`.
      label_length: tensor `(samples, 1)` containing the sequence length for
          each batch item in `y_true`.
  Returns:
      Tensor with shape (samples,1) containing the
          CTC loss of each element.
  """
  label_length = math_ops.cast(
      array_ops.squeeze(label_length, axis=-1), dtypes_module.int32)
  input_length = math_ops.cast(
      array_ops.squeeze(input_length, axis=-1), dtypes_module.int32)
  sparse_labels = math_ops.cast(
      ctc_label_dense_to_sparse(y_true, label_length), dtypes_module.int32)

  y_pred = math_ops.log(array_ops.transpose(y_pred, perm=[1, 0, 2]) + epsilon())

  return array_ops.expand_dims(
      ctc.ctc_loss(
          inputs=y_pred, labels=sparse_labels, sequence_length=input_length), 1)
```

Comment: If someone struggles with the import:
from tensorflow.python.keras.backend import ctc_label_dense_to_sparse, epsilon
from tensorflow.python.ops import math_ops, array_ops
from tensorflow.python.ops.gen_ctc_ops import ctc_loss
from tensorflow.python.framework import dtypes as dtypes_module

Answer (score 0):

you need to remove softmax in your dense output layer and replace it with log softmax because ctc loss needs log softmax output to perform loss calculation.